# Maven property with default value but customizable by external property file

Tags: maven

I would like to have a property `a` and `b` with default values `org.a` and `org.b` respectively.

I would like to override one or both with property files. I will use `properties-maven-plugin`

My pom is

```
<properties>
    <a>org.a</a>
    <b>org.b</b>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>load</id>
        <properties>
                <a>${x.a}</a>
                <b>${x.b}</b>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals><goal>read-project-properties</goal></goals>
                            <configuration><files><file>x</file></files></configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target><echo>hello, ${a} ${b} </echo></target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

File x content:

```
x.b=mod.b
```

Output of `mvn initialize` is

> hello, org.a org.b

That is OK

Output of `mvn initialize -Pload` is

Actual:

> [echo] hello, ${x.a} mod.b

Expected

> [echo] hello, org.a mod.b

How to achieve what I expect? I want avoid command like `mvn initialize -Pload -Da=org.a` or `mvn initialize -Db=mod.b` because I want read customization from property file. I don't want remove `<a>${x.a}</a>` from pom.xml because I want sometimes modify `a`

Comment: What is the purpose of this setup? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise, My application has good defaults, which I want to preserve. Next, I have several Jenkins jobs. One can create custom application server, second custom database, other both. I want each job call the build in the same way, let say `mvn install -Pload` but property file will vary from one job to another. I hope to get easy to maintain Jenkins when maven build is configurable through property files rather than command line parameters

Comment: Why doing different jobs for different configurations why not producing all artifacts in one job ?

Comment: @khmarbaise My final artifact is WAR with configuration for database and applicaction server. Configuration is built in the WAR. I want to have each job produce a bit different WAR with different default configuration. It easier to handle single self-sufficient WAR within concrete environment context that WAR + configuration

Comment: Yes of course. But i would generate all three in a single job which mean simply `mvn clean package` would produce three different artifacts (wars) with appropriate configurations. See here: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments/

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, that is interesting concept and I will study it. However, it does not apply well to my application. My Jenkins establish db and app server on Amazon, then create tailored WAR and process test on the environment. As environment details change each build (url, credentials), static properties is not suffiecient. I would like pass dynamic properties